# Align entered date in input[type='date'] in mobile browsers

Tags: html, css

I want to left-align the entered date in `input[type='date']`. However, on mobile browsers (I'm testing on safari and chrome), the date stays in the center of the `input`. [mobile example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyL2T.jpg)

**Here is the code I'm working with:**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.date-input {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="date" class="date-input" />
<div>
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/input-text-align-r1el0?file=/index.html:161-380)

Is there something I'm missing within the CSS, or do mobile browsers just force you to center the entered date within the `input`?

Comment: I don't think there's something you can do with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just ran a quick test on an iOS simulator linked to Safari dev tools and found that there is a pseudo element which we can style...

[image]

```css
input::-webkit-date-and-time-value {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Been looking for this all day, thanks!